# True Statement is False in Python with SQLalchemy... Why?

Tags: python, sql

i'm starting to code so this is my 1st message in the community.. thanks in advance. I'm sure i'll be able to cooperate sooner than later.

I've been trying to solve this problem for hours without success...
The idea is to get a password from a USERS table with SQLalchemy... i get it and that's ok, but when i compare it with the same string (input from a form), i'm getting a false.. i've tried to convert it to a string, and to get it with as an element of an array... no success... any ideas?? Thanks guys

In a summary, this is the relevant code to the question:

```
password = request.form["password"]
sql_pass = db.execute("select password from users where username=:user", {"user":user}).fetchone()
sql_pass = str(sql_pass[0])
password = str(password)
if password == sql_pass:
      test="true"
else:
      test="false"
return(f"{test} - password: {password} - sql_pass: {sql_pass}")
```

With this, we get:

```
false - password: 2 - sql_pass: 2
```

I'm getting False after tons of different attempts.... any help is more than welcome!

Comment: Can you print the strings you're trying to compare? What do they look like. Without that we're pretty much blind

Comment: There it is, i edited so there's more info. Thx

Comment: First, don’t use `execute()` if possible, build proper ORM `query()` statements. Second, what are the original types and why do you convert them to string? And: _**NEVER EVER**_ store passwords in a database, [store and compare hashes](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm), take a look at [bcrypt](https://github.com/pyca/bcrypt/)!

Comment: Thx Jens! This is for a project of the course i'm doing, in which they forbidden us to use ORM for now... so it's not for "real life". The original type in SQL is character(15)... i'm trying to convert them to string just as an attempt to transform them to the same type (but still doesn't work)... i'll have a look to bcrypt though! Thanks!! ... can you notice why this doesn't work though?

Comment: You could get the string representation of the two values in case you've got an integer or spaces `f"{test} - password: {password!r} - sql_pass: {sql_pass!r}"`

Comment: Thank tdelaney! That's very interesting because now it showed me a space at the end of sql_pass... how you manage that?  It returned: false - password: '2' - sql_pass: '2 '

Comment: @pipegnr - It must have been written that way - your password input code could do some extra normalization on strings - probably just password.strip(). Anyway, when debugging `repr(foo)` or in f strings `f"{foo!r}"` makes it easier to spot odd things like this.

Comment: @tdelaney thx a lot for helping a noob here! i could manage it thanks to you... genius!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects can appear to be equal, but this isn't the type of thing that python gets wrong. You did the right thing printing the two values, but there is more than one way to do that. In python `str` produces what the object thinks is its best human readable form. `repr` produces what the object thinks is its best programmatic name. For strings, for instance, this includes quotes which makes it easier to spot unexpected characters. The `!r` in f strings gives you that represenation

`f"{test} - password: {password!r} - sql_pass: {sql_pass!r}"`